# , identify its order being pop from stack

Tags: java

i am trying to print this output ***List contains:*** [-,+,**,+,/,-,*,/]

***Order of operators popped from stacks:*** - * + / + * /

i am using a method named ***identifyPrecedence()*** this method will determine the precedence of each operator (MDAS) and returns its corresponding value.

Another method name ***performedOperations()***  this methods holds a Linkedlist of characters as its parameter. i was not able to print the second output what should i do to print this second output which is the **Order of operators popped from stack: - * + / + * / ***

help me heres my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     LinkedList <String> Operator = new LinkedList <String> ();
            Operator.add("-");
            Operator.add("+");
            Operator.add("*");
            Operator.add("+");
            Operator.add("/");
            Operator.add("-");
            Operator.add("*");
            Operator.add("/");
            System.out.println("List Contains " + Operator);



            System.out.println("Order if operators popped from stack: " + wew);

        }
        public static char identifyPrecendence(LinkedList <Character>operators)

        {

            char Precedence = 0;

         if (operators.contains('*')||operators.contains('/')) 
         {
            Precedence = 2;
         }
          else if (operators.contains('-')||operators.contains('+'))
          {
               Precedence=1;
          }
         return Precedence;

        }
          public static LinkedList <Character> performedOperations(LinkedList <Character>operators)
          {
              System.out.println("List Contains: "+operators);

        LinkedList <Character>wew=new LinkedList();
    Stack sp=new Stack();
    sp.push(operators);

            if(identifyPrecedence(operators)>=2){

          sp.remove(operators.contains(sp));
          }
         System.out.println("Order of operators popped from stack: "+sp);

                return operators;
          }

        private static int identifyPrecedence(LinkedList<Character> operators) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        private static String identifyPrecedence() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `operators` contain all of those? Did you ask the same question under a different username? Or is the same class just not collaborating?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971897/given-its-order-of-operator-identify-its-order-being-pop-from-stack

Comment: no i am new to stack overflow i saw  this question and i am also self studying in java i also dont get the right answer..